# Override maxSdkVersion used by library

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-manifest

Here's the scenario. My app (A) is using a library (B).

My app (A) is using permission READ_PHONE_STATE and it's declared in manifest.xml as

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

While library (B) is also using the same permission READ_PHONE_STATE, but with maxSdkVersion set to 22.

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="22"/>
```

So now the problem is when app is built and in the final _merged_manifest_ I'm having *maxSdkVersion="22"* set, and because of this my current device which is running nougat can't request for this particular permission.

Currently I found a solution to override this value in my app (A) manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission
    tools:replace="android:maxSdkVersion"
    android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="28"/>
```

But this requires me to update *maxSdkVersion* every time I update the sdk version in my app (A).

So my question is

1. Is there a way to ignore maxSdkVersion set by library (B) using some namespace in my manifest.xml like tools:ignore
2. Set maxSdkVersion to latest sdkVersion in build.gradle automatically without manually changing it

Comment: Try `tools:replace="attr, ..."` and Marker selector in https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#node_markers

Comment: I found tools:ignore as a viable substitute.

Comment: why should you set maxSdkVersion?

Comment: Because tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" instructs the device to ignore this permission if device's version is >= 22.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `tools:remove` attribute on your own `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
    tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"/>
```